# Android: Global variable becomes null on returning to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment, say A in my app from which I start an activity for result using

```
private void openComputationWindow(final int pos) {

// code here

    result = new Button(mActivity);
    result.setText("Select");
    result.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    result.setPadding(0, 30, 0, 20);
    layout.addView(result);

    result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
            getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
    });

// code here

}
```

The second activity has a fragment added to it. In this fragment I perform some operations and return the result back to the previous activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
                        fm.popBackStack();
                    }
                    getActivity().setResult(1, intent);
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
```

The problem is that in my fragment A I use this data to setText in textView result, the same textView from which I launched the intent. I declare this textView as a global variable so that it can be accessed inside onActivity result. But I get null pointer exception when setting text to result textView. I don't know why it becomes null, is the fragment being reinitialized? Though I have done similar task earlier but I never faced an issue. Can someone please help me. Thanks !!

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        result.setText(path);
    }
```

Edit: I must mention that I have reused the fragment at another portion in my app and I perform the same function there and it works perfectly over there. There is however I a slight difference. I have a view pager which is hosted inside a fragment. I am using the fragment A as one of the viewpager tabs as well as the child of another viewpager tab, lets say B. The problem comes when I use it as the child of Fragment B.

Comment: add your fragment a complete code.

Comment: when is `result` initialised?

Comment: check if id is proper

Comment: @USKMobility I have added the relevant code, complete fragment has too much code.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I initialize it inside the function from where I launch the intent, I have added the code. Please have a look.

Comment: @ArjunHegde which id?

Comment: Please add crash log

Answer (score -1):

I don't see where is the variable **result** initialized.
you must initialize like this:

TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.YourTextView);